# How can we log errors in firebase (android, kotlin)?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm able to fire many events using firebase, **how can I log an error which can appear in the below orange background?**

I tried crashing the application.

I tried overriding firebase_error and app_exception events

```
mFirebaseAnalytics?.logEvent("firebase_error", bundle)
mFirebaseAnalytics?.logEvent("app_exception", bundle)
```

Didn't find any firebase error logging event as well, only thing to log any event is this

```
mFirebaseAnalytics?.logEvent(string, bundle)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can put errors as exceptions into `Firebase Crashlytics` instead of `Firebase Analytics` and they will appear as non-fatal.

```
Firebase.crashlytics.recordException(exception)
```